# Can I amend previous commit any number of times until it is pushed to remote?

Tags: git

So the scenario is,
I committed some changes to local branch. After sometime I realized it should be amended, so did an amend.
After some spec changes I am again in the need of an amend.
So practically it will only be a single commit when I'll push it to remote or what?
All I need is a cleaner history.

Comment: Yes. The history will be same as the output of `git log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. And before pushing, you can do this unlimited times. As described on [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History):

> [...] first make the changes you think you forgot, stage those changes, and the subsequent `git commit --amend` replaces that last commit with your new, improved commit.

[Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189600/2387977), you can also do a lot of local commits and use `git squash` (or just using [soft reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/2387977)) to create one single commit before pushing on repository:

> It’s also possible to take a series of commits and squash them down into a single commit with the interactive rebasing tool.
>
> [...] When you save that, you have a single commit that introduces the changes of all three previous commits.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to hear about `git squash`.